# installing joint_state_publisher

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am trying to install joint_state_publisher but it isn't working. how should it be done?
i did this- sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-JKU-Robotic-Stack
and got error E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-JKU-Robotic-Stack
i tried git https://github.com/AaronMR/JKU_Robotic_Stack.git
and got error .
how should it be done?
Thanks
Nachum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43502/installing-joint_state_publisher/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-09-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it just worked.
git clone https://github.com/AaronMR/JKU_Robotic_Stack.git

---

Originally posted by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) with karma: 208 on 2012-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-09-10**:
does it mean that noww the package is installed?